# Removing a div on button click - issue: removing all divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

On a button click event a new div is created. A user can create as many divs as possible.  Once a `div` is created it becomes draggable thanks to the help of the jqueryui draggable [PLUGIN](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/). I have set another on click button event that removes the created div. The problem is that when clicking the user clicks the remove button it removes all divs. How can append a button to each `div` that specifically removes that div? [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/bullseye2346/0wbnud4k/33/)

Jquery

```
/** Remove newly created div **/
$(".remove").click(function(){
    $(".draggable").remove();
});
var z = 1;
$('#button').click(function (e) {
    /** Make div draggable **/
    $('<div />', {
        class: 'draggable ui-widget-content',
        text: $('textarea').val(),
        appendTo: '.middle-side',
        draggable: {
            containment: 'parent',
            start: function( event, ui ) {
                $(this).css('z-index', ++z);
            }
        }
    }).addClass('placement');

    /** Contain draggable div **/
    $('.middle-side').parent().mousemove(function(e){
        var offset = $(this).offset();
        var relX = e.pageX - offset.left;
        var relY = e.pageY - offset.top;
        $('.placement').css({'top': relY + 30,'left': relX + 10, 'position': 'absolute'});
    })
});
```

HTML

```
<textarea rows="4" cols="50" placeholder="Enter Text Here!"></textarea><br/>
<input type="button" id="button" value="Add Div with Text" />
<button class="remove">Remove div</button><br/>
<div>
    <div class="middle-side empty"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Turn the `text` property to `html`:

```
html: '<span class="close">[X]</span><span class="text">' + $('textarea').val() + '</span>',
```

Then write `click` event for `.close` elements:

```
$('body').on('click', '.draggable .close', function () {
    $(this).closest('.draggable').remove();
});
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/0wbnud4k/35/).

Comment: could you help here please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25600101/containing-a-draggable-div-to-parent

Answer (score 1):

Modify your Add Div Button and Remove Button event like this:

```
$(".remove").click(function(){
    $(".currentDiv").remove();
});

var z = 1;
$('#button').click(function (e) {
    $(".currentDiv").removeClass("currentDiv");
    /** Make div draggable **/
    $('<div />', {
        class: 'draggable ui-widget-content',
        text: $('textarea').val(),
        appendTo: '.middle-side',
        draggable: {
            containment: 'parent',
            start: function( event, ui ) {
                $(this).css('z-index', ++z);
        },
        drag: function() {
            $(".currentDiv").removeClass("currentDiv");
            $(this).addClass("currentDiv");
        },
    }
}).addClass('placement currentDiv');
```

In this way when you create a new div, all `currentDiv` classes are removed in this line:

```
$(".currentDiv").removeClass("currentDiv");
```

Then the `currentDiv` class is added in created div in last line. So always the last created div has `currentDiv` class.

Then add this block at the end of your JS:

```
$('body').on('click', '.draggable', function () {
    $(".currentDiv").removeClass("currentDiv");
    $(this).addClass("currentDiv"); 
});
```

The above block cause that when you click on each draggable element, it selected as current div so Remove button, remove that.

**[Check JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/0wbnud4k/42/)**

In demo i have also add a background-color:red for currentDiv, you can remove it.

Comment: But it on allows me to remove the latest created div. What happens if I want to remove the first created div?

Comment: @Code_Ed_Student: Sorry for late, it seems you mark another post as answer but i think i provide a better solution without close button, check the updated answer Demo and let me know the result.

Comment: @Code_Ed_Student: The code has a problem that when you drag a div it doesn't select and yo need to click on it but in updated answer this problem has been solved.

Comment: +1 @Moshtaf this is a great implementation as well but I have already chosen an answer. Although I do have another question about editing text on a div: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25594009/appending-text-and-editing-text-of-div-button-click-event

Comment: @Code_Ed_Student: My main goal was completing answer as a perfect answer not be marked as answer. But if you think it's a better solution for your problem you can change the answer mark easily. It could be helpful for future readers.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add this after `draggable` event :

```
var closeBtn = '<a href="#xcv" onclick="$(this).unwrap();$(this).remove();" >close</a>';
$('.placement').append(closeBtn);
```

[**JSFIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/0wbnud4k/38/)